# Office Addins - Unable to fetching attachments

Tags: office-addins

I am trying to develop an Add-in for Outlook, for that I have cloned this repo (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-JavaScript-GetAttachments) and have followed the instructions mentioned there.

My question is, when my add-in makes a request to https://localhost:44320/api/AttachmentService, it sends back a response with the following content:

`{
  "isError": false,
  "message": null,
  "attachmentsProcessed": 2,
  "attachmentNames": [
    "avatar-1606916_960_720.png",
    "HnVmB0-k.jpg"
  ]
}`

But it does not tell me the URL of my attachment using which i can view the attachment.

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no links to the repo you have used as well as instructions you have used. Please review.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Link added now. Thanks